# run python script forever, without care about errors

Tags: python, error-handling

I need to run a python script to send me a email hourly, with some log information.
The problem is that the server fails temporarily, then my python scrips returns to bash.

I try while true, but it still returning to bash when connection is down.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job, look at cron (or an equivalent for Windows, if that's what you're on)

Comment: Some code will be nice....

Comment: You're looking for a tool like supervisor: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor

Comment: The problem isn't probably on the Python side of things. Try something like this to rule this out completely: `while True: try: #do whatever it is you're doing here except: pass`. This will continue working even if any errors are raised in the Python script.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the code within a try and except statement.
so it will be:

```
while True:
    try:
        # Your code
    except:
        pass
```

Here the code will continue to run and if it encounters an error it won't execute you code but the while loop will continue.

Answer (score 2):

Use a try..except statement:

```
while True:
    try:
        send(text)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.log(e)
```